# How to add up amount of data from an external file in C# (Stream Reader)

Tags: c#, variables, loops, while-loop, streamreader

I'm new to this site, and pretty new to programming, at the moment I'm trying to display a count amount for the users names on my donation list, and then I also want to have a sum to work out the total amount of money the donation list contains, If someone could help me with creating a way to add up amount of donors on the donations.txt file that would be great help, I have no idea where to start, but so far this is my coding:

```
        string sName;
        double dAmount;
        string sTotalNames;
        double dAmountTotal;
        double dAmountAverage;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Donations.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            sName = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(sName);

            dAmount = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(dAmount);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the format of `Donations.txt` and expected results for that sample.

Comment: Within it is just written string names & doubles which I obtained to the file by using my Stream Writer, the following information in it currently is: Alex
50
Bob
45
Sam
90
Sarah
33
Harry
60

Comment: I basically just want to add up the strings within the external file and display a total within my reader program, and same for the amount donated

Comment: it sounds like it should be xml like <User Name="Alex"><Amount>50</Amount></User>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything else you have works correctly, creating a sum would be pretty easy.

```
string sName;
double dAmount;
int sTotalNames = 0;
double dAmountTotal = 0;
double dAmountAverage;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Donations.txt"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        sName = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(sName);

        dAmount = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(dAmount);
        dAmountTotal += dAmount;
        sTotalNames++;
    }
    dAmountAverage = dAmountTotal / sTotalNames;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}", dAmountTotal );
    Console.WriteLine("Total Names = {0}", sTotalNames);
    Console.WriteLine("Average Amount = {0}", dAmountAverage);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves my total amount issue, any idea how I would add up the amount of donators?

Comment: Thanks a lot kevin, your answer was great help, even added in the average code for me, I will accept your answer as the solution when it allows me to, Thanks so much again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah no problem, figured you wanted that as well since you had a variable declared for it.

Comment: Yeah I thought that's why you did it for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
List<double> dAmountList = new List<double>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Donations.txt"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        sName = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(sName);

        dAmount = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(dAmount);
        dAmountList.Add(dAmount);

    }

    double sum = dAmountList.Sum(); //here you have your sum

    int dAmountOfDonators = dAmountList.Count(); //here you have your donators total count

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick & compact implementation:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Donations.txt");

// Convert odd rows to Double
var amounts = lines.Where((x,i) => i % 2 == 1)
                   .Select(Convert.ToDouble)
                   .ToArray();

var sum = amounts.Sum();
var count = amounts.Count();
```